# GET Max array from two array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want which is the biggest array from following array.

```
 [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 9
        )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 8
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 13
    )
```

I want a code that would return last array with key 33.
Please Help.

Comment: max(array_keys($your_array));

Comment: What do u mean by the biggest array? is it total sum?

Comment: @Nouphal M Compare all values from all array and return array which has highest value from all array.and it is not like that maximum key will come at last.

Comment: you mean `13` is the largest number so `33` index will be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Use max to get the maximum from the keys of your array

```
$yourarray=array(13 => Array
(
    0 => 1,
            1 => 3,
            2 => 9,
        ),

15 => Array
(
    0 => 1,
        1 => 5,
        2 => 8,
    ),

33 => Array
(
    0 => 1,
        1 => 9,
        2 => 13,
    ));
$arr=max(array_keys($yourarray));
print_r($yourarray[$arr]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 13
)
```

Comment: Key is not always going to bigger at last.It is not like that array with max key is the highest one.

Comment: @user2645436 Check my answer it returning the value of the highest key in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
<?php

$tests = array(
    13 => array(1,3,9),
    15 => array(1,5,8),
    33 => array(1,9,13)
);

$array_totals = array_map('array_sum', $tests);
krsort($array_totals);
$maxArray = each($array_totals);

var_dump($maxArray);
```

Gives

```
array (size=4)
  1 => int 23
  'value' => int 23
  0 => int 33
  'key' => int 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most beautiful thing, but readable ;)

```
$tests = array(
    13 => array(1,3,9),
    15 => array(1,5,8),
    33 => array(1,9,13)
);

$max = -1;
$max_key = -1;
foreach ($tests as $k => $v) {
    $cur_max = max($v);
    if ($cur_max >= $max) {
        $max = $cur_max;
        $max_key = $k;
    }
}

echo "max: $max; max_key: $max_key";
```

Gives:

```
max: 13; max_key: 33
```

To make it more beautiful: use `array_map` and sorting.

Comment: Note to all: His question is a bit unclear, but what he wants is simply the index of the array that contains the biggest value.